# error: explicit specialization of undeclared template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have this interface:

```
template <class T>
    class Builder {
        public:
            // Virtual destructor
            virtual ~Builder(){}
            // Builds a concrete instance of the implementor
            virtual T build() const =0;
    };
```

and the following concrete implementation:

```
template <class T>
    class ConcreteBuilder<T> : Builder<T> {
        public:
            // Virtual destructor
            virtual ~ConcreteBuilder(){}
            // override the build() base method from Builder<T>
            virtual T build() override {
                return 0;
            }
    };
```

Suppose the next mock:

```
class MockedClass {
    public:
        std::string return_hi() const {
            return std::string {"Hi!"};
        }

        int return_num() const {
            return 10;
        }
};
```

And the following:

```
MockedClass mc;
std::cout << mc.return_hi() << std::endl;
std::cout << mc.return_num() << std::endl;

ConcreteBuilder<MockedClass>;
```

And the error:

```
error: explicit specialization of undeclared template class 'ConcreteBuilder'
```

If I remove the `class` parameter from the declaration of `ConcreteBuilder`:
`class ConcreteBuilder : Builder<T>` everything works, but I have the doubt about
what I am allowed to do this:

`ConcreteBuilder;` (no type parameters)

1 - Why this error happens?
2 - How can I constraint my `ConcreteBuilder` in order to make mandatory to specify the
type parameter for `ConcreteBuilder`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax to inherit from `Builder<T>` while defining the `ConcreteBuilder` template would be as shown below:

```
template <class T>
//-------------------v------------------->removed <T> from here
class ConcreteBuilder : Builder<T> {
    public:
        // Virtual destructor
        virtual ~ConcreteBuilder(){}
        // override the build() base method from Builder<T>
        virtual T build() override {
            return 0;
        }
};
```

Comment: As I wrote above, code compiles fine when I define the `ConcreteBuilder` in that way, but I am able to make a non-parametrized instance of `ConcreteBuilder`, while my desire it's to provide an API that requires a type parameter, in this case of type `MockedClass` as follows: `ConcreteBuilder<MockedClass>`, without losing the `Build` interface bound. Also, I can write that bound with the type parameter on `ConcreteBuilder`if I remove `T` from the declaration of `ConcreteBuilder`, but also instanciante a ConcreteBuilder without it, and there it's where I am struggling.

Comment: @AlexVergara Look carefully at my answer, i didn't remove the class parameter from `ConcretBuilder`. So you will be able to pass a type parameter without any problem as you want. That is you can still write `ConcreteBuilder<MockedClass>;` as before. That is, your claim that *"but I am able to make a non-parametrized instance of ConcreteBuilder"* is wrong.

Comment: You're right. I am able to write this: `TestBuilder;` as an standalone statement, but I am not able to generate an instance `auto itce = TestBuilder {}`. This throws: `no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'TestBuilder'`.

Comment: I am still getting mad at how I can write `TestBuilder` without getting a compile error.

Comment: @AlexVergara If you try it in different compilers and with strict warnings enabled you'll get your desired compiler error. Try out your code [here online](https://godbolt.org/z/o3fejjKvj) and play with some warning flags to get the compiler error. I am sure you'll get the compiler error at least in one of the compiler even without using any extra flags in the above given link.

Comment: Yep. Good advice there. So, it's a vendor dependant issue, not a language standard definition.
Warnings as errors in `Clang` already fits the question.

Thanks for your time.